# Custom Error Page in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

When visiting a page pointing to shiny app, such as myshinyapp.com/NoSuchPage.html, shiny will return "Not Found" information page. I suppose it is error 404 page.

How can I replace this "Not Found" page with my own page?

Thanks.

Comment: See @hrbrmstr's answer for how to do this for pages that Shiny Server handles. Do be aware that *shiny* (not Shiny Server) also has to generate these pages, at times (if you're inside a Shiny App and ask for a resource that doesn't exist). Shiny doesn't yet expose a way to control its internal error pages.

Answer (score 6):

From section 2.10 of [the manual](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/):

> Shiny Server can utilize custom templates when generating static pages such as directory indexes and error pages. This feature is controlled using the `template_dir` directive and can be applied globally, or to a particular server or location.
>
> To utilize this feature, you'll need a directory in which you'll store your templates. In this example, we'll assume you're using `/etc/shiny-server/templates/`. Inside this directory, you'll place the `handlebars-enabled` HTML templates for your pages.
>
> Shiny Server will attempt to find a specific page to accommodate the current need -- for instance, if it encountered a 404 error, it will first look to see if you provided a specific template for handling 404 errors in the specified directory (`error-404.html`). If it doesn't find this file, it will go one step backwards to see if you provide a generic error template (`error.html`). If it can't find a suitable template in your template directory, it will fall back to use the provided templates that come with Shiny Server (and are stored in `/opt/shiny-server/templates`).
>
> As you may have noticed already, Shiny Server uses a hyphen-delimited hierarchy which progresses from broadest to narrowest. So all error pages start with error. But the file name for a 404 error page would add an additional element (404) following a hyphen: `error-404`. All files are expected to use the `.html` extension.